# Mapped state array not returning components (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am trying to render one UserItem component for each user in the JSON data set. The page renders with no errors, but no UserItem's are output. Another pair of eyes would be greatly appreciated.

**my-app/src/assets/data/data.json**

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Bart",
      "age": 10
    },
    {
      "name": "Lisa",
      "age": 8
    },
    {
      "name": "Maggie",
      "age": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

**my-app/src/assets/components/UserList.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { UserItem } from './UserItem';

import importedData from '../data/data.json';

export class UserList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state={
      users: []
    };
 }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({users: importedData.data});
    this.setState(this.state);
  }

  render () {
    return (
        <div className="user-list">
          <ul>
            {
              this.state.users.map((user) => {
                return <UserItem name={user.name} age={user.age} />
              )}
            }
          </ul>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default UserList;
```

**my-app/src/assets/components/UserItem.js**

```
import React from 'react';

export class UserItem extends React.Component {
    render () {
    return (
      <li className="user-item">
        <div className="name">{this.props.user.name}</div>
        <div className="age">{this.props.user.age}</div>
      </li>
    );
  }
}

export default UserItem;
```

**rendered HTML**

```
  <div class="user-list">
    <ul></ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: What is the second setState call for?

Comment: setState doesn't immediately make changes, which - in this case - was resulting in .map() trying to operate on an empty array. The second setState basically makes the first one 'finish'. I acknowledge that it's hacky, but it gets the job done.

Comment: ... at least, that was my understanding. I'm still a n00b, so likely misinformed.

Comment: Interesting, I just had not seen it before.  Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should delete the keyword `export` before your class in the two js files since you export them in the last line. Also the `this.setState(this.state);` serves no purpose. In the UserItem.js you write this.props.user.name/age where you pass name and age as props. So:

```
import React from 'react';

class UserItem extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return (
          <li className="user-item">
            <div className="name">{this.props.name}</div>
            <div className="age">{this.props.age}</div>
          </li>
        );
    }
}

export default UserItem;
```

Comment: there is `export class UserItem` and `export default UserItem;` maybe pick one?